# ipython notebook does not launch since installing python 3 on mac os x yosemite

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, crash, jupyter-notebook

I was enjoying my ipython notebook on my MacPro running OS X Yosemite, which was running python 2.7.

Then, I installed python 3.4, but forgot to double click the "Update Shell Profile.command" file in the Applications/Python3.4 folder.

When I ran ipython notebook afterward, I noticed that I could choose between python 2.7 and python 3 kernels. When I chose the python 3 kernel, it would try to start, but die.

I shutdown my ipython notebook, and the next time I tried to launch it, I received the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/ipython", line 11, in 
>           sys.exit(start_ipython())
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/**init**.py", line 118, in start_ipython
>           return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
>           app.initialize(argv)
>         File "", line 2, in initialize
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
>           return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
>           super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
>         File "", line 2, in initialize
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
>           return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
>           self.parse_command_line(argv)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
>           return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
>         File "", line 2, in parse_command_line
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
>           return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
>           return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
>         File "", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
>           return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
>           subapp = import_item(subapp)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
>           module = **import**(package, fromlist=[obj])
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 32, in 
>           from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/**init**.py", line 44, in 
>           _libsodium = ctypes.CDLL(bundled_sodium[0], mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ctypes/**init**.py", line 351, in **init**
>           self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>       OSError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so.orig, 10): Symbol not found: _Py_InitModule4_64
>         Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so.orig
>         Expected in: flat namespace
>        in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/libsodium.so.orig

I've uninstalled ipython, deleted the .ipython directory, and then reinstalled ipython to no avail.

Any advice would be very welcome.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the following procedure worked for me:

1. uninstall the 2.7 version found in:

   ~/Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions
2. Download the Mac installer for Python 2.7.10 found here:
   [Mac Python Downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/)

Then, as a test, try launching IPython from Terminal.app by typing

```
$ipython
```

If that is successful, then try launching an IPython notebook from Terminal

```
$ipython notebook
```